# select array ruby - Using select to get a >= 4 capacity

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use select to get capacity >= 4 on this:

```
class Home
  attr_reader(:name, :city, :capacity, :price)

  def initialize(name, city, capacity, price)
    @name = name
    @city = city
    @capacity = capacity
    @price = price
  end
end

homes = [
  Home.new("Nizar's place", "San Juan", 2, 42),
  Home.new("Fernando's place", "Seville", 5, 47),
  Home.new("Josh's place", "Pittsburgh", 3, 41),
  Home.new("Gonzalo's place", "Málaga", 2, 45),
  Home.new("Ariel's place", "San Juan", 4, 49)
]
```

I tried:

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  hm.capacity >= 4
  puts high_capacities_homes
end
```

without any success and im out of ideas, can someone pls help? :(

Comment: `homes.select {|a| a.capacity >= 4}`

Comment: `puts` anything returns `nil`. Simply remove the line with `puts` and insert `puts` before `high_capacities_homes`.

Comment: sidenote: I can see errors easily occurring during initialization, say if the arguments are put in the wrong order.. perhaps you'd be better off using a hash and redefining your initialize method accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  hm.capacity >= 4
end

puts high_capacities_homes
```

`puts` returns nil so all your blocks evaluated to false.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at what is happening. When you execute your code you get the following.

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  hm.capacity >= 4
  puts high_capacities_homes
end





 => []
```

An empty array is returned, but why all those blank lines? It's because your code is executing `puts nil` for each element of `homes`. Consider this:

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  hm.capacity >= 4
  puts "high_capacities_homes is nil: #{high_capacities_homes.nil?}"
end
high_capacities_homes is nil: true
high_capacities_homes is nil: true
high_capacities_homes is nil: true
high_capacities_homes is nil: true
high_capacities_homes is nil: true
 => []
```

When Ruby sees

```
high_capacities_homes = <anything>
```

the first thing she does is create a local variable `high_capacities_homes` and assign it the value `nil`. Only after `select` is finished enumerating `homes` is `high_capacities_homes` assigned the return value of `select`'s block, namely, `[]`.

There is another problem. The first line of your method,

```
hm.capacity >= 4
```

returns `true` or `false`, but that return value is not acted upon. It's as though it's just been shot out into space, never to be seen again, making your code equivalent to:

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  puts high_capacities_homes
end
```

Since puts returns `nil` (after printing whatever it's printing), for the purpose of constructing the array `high_capacities_homes` your code amounts to:

```
high_capacities_homes = homes.select do |hm|
  nil
end
```

which is why no elements of `homes` were selected.

Do you wish to create an array of the elements `hm` of `homes` for which `hm.capacity >= 4` (as well as print information about those instances)? If so, first select the elements of `homes` you want:<sup>1</sup>.

```
selected_homes = homes.select { |hm| hm.capacity >= 4 }
  # => [#<Home:0x007ff81981e138 @name="Fernando's place", @city="Seville",
  #       @capacity=5, @price=47>,
  #     #<Home:0x007ff81981dda0 @name="Ariel's place", @city="San Juan",
  #       @capacity=4, @price=49>]
```

Note that [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select) keeps all elements `hm` of `homes` for which `select`'s block returns `true`.

Now, what do you want to print? If it's the values of the instance variables of each element of `selected_homes`, you can do that as follows (as an example).

```
selected_homes.each { |hm|
  puts "#{hm.name} in #{hm.city} has capacity #{hm.capacity} and price $#{hm.price}" }
```

prints

```
Fernando's place in Seville has capacity 5 and price $47
Ariel's place in San Juan has capacity 4 and price $49
```

<sup>1 You could, of course, instead write `selected_homes = homes.reject { |hm| hm.capacity < 4 }`.</sup>